# Add Breadcrumb Menu to Orchard CMS 1.5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, orchardcms

Using Orchard 1.5 (which supposedly has built in support for breadcrumbs) I am confused on how to add a breadcrumb to specific pages.  For example, I have a Bio's page.  I want a breadcrumb added to the top of the page that looks like this:

Home > Bios > John Doe

Do I do it from the "Bios" Content Type, from the Navigation option on the left or where?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a menu widget, configure it to display as breadcrumbs.

Comment: Thanks.  It wasn't obvious to me to look under the Widgets.  Is there a way to add it to only certain content types, or once added as a widget, will it always appear on all pages?  For example, let's say I don't want it to appear on the Home Page or Contact Us page.  How would I do that?

Comment: Create a layer and give it a rule that says not url("~/") and not url("~/contact-us"). Put your widget into that layer.

Comment: Have a look at http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Navigation-and-menus 
Document changes still need to be approved.